# Purpose of toIterable

Tags: scala, collections

In [scala exercies](https://github.com/scala-exercises/exercises-stdlib/blob/master/src/main/scala/stdlib/Traversables.scala) I have found the following example:

```
val set = Set(4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14)
val result = set.toIterable
```

with the following description:

> `toIterable` will convert any `Traversable` to an `Iterable.` This is a base trait for all Scala collections that define an iterator method to iterate through the collection's elements

But `Set` is already an `Iterable`, so what's the point of this method? If this isn't the valid case, could you point me one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala 2.13 there is [no more `Traversable`](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0):

> **Simpler type hierarchy**
>
> No more `Traversable` and `TraversableOnce`. They remain only as
>   deprecated aliases for `Iterable` and `IterableOnce`.

Calling [`toIterable`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#toIterable:Iterable.this.type) on `Set` is redundant as it will simply return this same collection:

> This collection as an `Iterable[A]`. **No new collection will be built if
>   this is already an `Iterable[A]`**.

Examples where `toIterable` would have an effect would be

```
"Hello".toIterable
Array(1).toIterable
```

which implicitly converts to

```
wrapString("Hello").toIterable
wrapIntArray(Array(1)).toIterable
```

and make these Java-like types into Scala collections proper.

Comment: So was there any purpose for this method before scala 2.13?

Comment: @Andronicus There is still a purpose, for example, `Array(1,2,3).toIterable`, translates to `wrapIntArray(Array(1,2,3)).toIterable` and makes `Array` which is Scala's representation of Java's `T[]` an `Iterable`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mario Galic's answer, the other thing it does is change the static type. If you and the compiler knew it was a `Set` before the call, you don't know afterwards. Though the same can be achieved with a type ascription

```
val result: Iterable[Int] = set
```

(and this will work for strings and arrays as well), then you need to write out the type parameter, which may much more complex than `Int`.

> Why would I use it? If i know it's a Set, why would I change the type to Iterable?

1. it can be in a method which can be overridden and doesn't have to return `Set` in subclasses:

   ```
   class Super {
     def someValues = {
       val set = ... // you want to avoid duplicates
       set
     }
   }

   class Sub : Super {
     override def someValues = {
       List(...) // happens to have duplicates this time
     }
   ```

   doesn't compile, but would if `Super#someValues` returned `set.toIterable` (though it's generally good practice to have explicit return types).
2. It can influence later inferred types:

   ```
   val arr = Array(set)
   arr(0) = List(0, 1, 2, 3)
   ```

   doesn't compile, but would with `Array(set.toIterable)`.

Comment: Why would I use it? If i know it's a `Set`, why would I change the type to `Iterable`?

Comment: I've added a couple of examples.